# Vuex state not getting latest value

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to get updated value of name from state. But it's not returning the value in component. However, if I delay 1 second, it gets the value.

Component where I am not getting the latest value:

```
store.commit('updateName', 'asdas');       
console.log(store.state.name).
```

Here is my store.js

````
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

import { router } from '../router'

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        name: null,
        address: ''
    },
    mutation: {
        updateName(state, name){
            state.name = name
        },
        updateAddress(state, address){
            state.address = address
        }
    },
});```
````

Edited

I managed to get watch in mounted on component.

```
store.watch(store.getters.getName, name => {
    this.name = name;
  });
},
```

But if I print this.name under created(), it does not get the real value.

Comment: It should be `mutations` (plural), right? But that might not be the issue since you said the state would update, with some delays. Anyways, where in the code are you commiting this mutation?

Comment: You would need a watcher or a computed property which gets the latest store values after u perform the commit.

Comment: @nara_l Any sample?

Comment: Are you trying to access the value of `name` in the created() lifecycle hook? What action does the user take to update the `name` value and where does the new `name` value come from?